Programmatically specify a value within appsettings.json
I am trying to set up a logging system that adds log files to subfolders based on the year.  However I've been unable to programmatically specify the year.  I can hardcode it and it works fine, but I would like to be able to specify it programmatically.  When I do this, ASP.Net takes it as a literal value and either creates a folder based on that literal string, or it doesn't do anything because the string contains characters that can't exist (or can't start) a folder name, such as the example I'm showing below.  Is there a way to do this or am I stuck with hardcoding?
"Serilog": 
{
    "MinimumLevel": 
    {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": 
        {
            "Microsoft": "Information",
            "System": "Information"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": 
            {
            "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Logger","Args": 
            {
                "configureLogger": 
                    {
                        "WriteTo": 
                        [
                            {
                                "Name": "File",
                                "Args": 
                                {
                                    "path": "C:/data/Logs/ErrorLogs/{Date:yyyy}/errorlog_.log",
                                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                                    "retainedFileCountLimit": null,
                                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Filter": 
                        [
                            {
                                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                                "Args": 
                                {
                                    "expression": "(@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal')"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },

...

Which logger are you using? Serilog? Log4Net? Or something else? (This avoids needing to guess.)

@Richard - as the code shows above as well as my tag, Serilog.

You can can certainly do this in code (see readme). But nothing looks like the implementation treats the path from configuration as anything more than a plain string.

After a bunch more research and testing I found a solution to this - instead of using appsettings.json, you can make similar configurations to Serilog sink files in your program.cs, so here is the one that I ended up that worked for me:
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(); // Get the current year

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration) // Read other settings from appsettings.json
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
.WriteTo.File($"C:/data/Logs/ErrorLogs/{currentYear}/errorlog_.log",

    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    retainedFileCountLimit: null,
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",

    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error)
// Filter for Error and Fatal
.WriteTo.File($"C:/data/Logs/ActivityLogs/{currentYear}/activitylog_.log",
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    retainedFileCountLimit: null,
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.WithProperty<Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel>("Level",
                         level => level != Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)) // Filter for Information only
    .Filter.ByExcluding(le =>
        le.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains("The file ") || // More specific for "The File"
        le.RenderMessage().StartsWith("Request") || // Use RenderMessage for "Request" 
        le.MessageTemplate.Text.StartsWith("Executing") ||
        le.MessageTemplate.Text.StartsWith("Route") ||
        le.MessageTemplate.Text.StartsWith("Accessing") ||
        le.MessageTemplate.Text.StartsWith("Executed"))
.CreateLogger();

